# HttpRequest handle time delay between POST response and GET request Http

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, android-handler, postdelayed

I am working on an application which require following step to acquire data

> Step 1: Post a request to Http server using POST method which will send a part link in response.
>
> Step 2: Construct a full URL suing the response part link and request to server with URL using GET method.
>
> Setp 3: In response, we will receive the data which we need.

Now the problem is, it take some time to generate data when we pass a request to the server. Because of that i am constatly getting Null Pointer Error.
Is there any way i can delay request between POST and GET methods? or say i want to delay for sometime after receving the URL, so that the data get generated in server.
I tried using PostDelayed method but it's not working.
I am new to this so please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Same issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234261/using-both-post-and-get-http-request-in-asynctask

Comment: Yep..but i got no solution yet.. :(